# File path with file name of certain extension

Tags: linux, powershell, shell, jenkins

We are creating a Windows powershell script to upload the results, to the server and here is the problem

Everytime our execution completes, results are saved in a zip folder with timestamp.
For ex:

```
TestRun_12_Jan_2021.zip
TestRun_13_Feb_2021.zip 
etc
```

Problem is while assigning the above to a variable for further processing

We tried the below

```
$zippath = "(ENV:WORSKPACE)\Reports\*.zip"
$zippath = "(ENV:WORSKPACE)\Reports\TestRun*.zip"
```

and echoing it just prints

```
"<Actual_Workspace_Path>\Reports\*.zip"
```

but does not seem to pick the file during processing. How do i assign file with extension to the variable?

But when rename the file to 'Reports.zip' and set the path to

```
$zippath = "(ENV:WORSKPACE)\Reports\Reports.zip"
```

it works.

How do I make it work in the first case?

There will always be one .zip file in the directory because jenkins workspace is cleaned before every run.

Comment: Try `$zippath = "$env:WORKSPACE\Reports\Reports.zip"` (you had a typo in WORKSPACE too)

Comment: A more complete example of what you are trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: @zett42 : Typo was my bad. Erick's answer worked for me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning the string to then look for the file, try to make use of `Resolve-Path` function like

```
$zippath = Resolve-Path -Path "(ENV:WORSKPACE)\Reports\*.zip"
$zippath = Resolve-Path -Path "(ENV:WORSKPACE)\Reports\TestRun*.zip"
```

You can look for further reference of the function here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/resolve-path?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked for me and i was able to successfully upload using the above. Thanks again :)